# On google spreadsheet: Is there a way to change the content of a specific cell right after a someone submit a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

On Google spreadsheet: Is there a way to change the content of a specific cell right after a someone submit a form?

Every time someone submits a form, a row is added to the spreadsheet that contains the information of the spreadsheet on different columns. I want to have the spreadsheet automatically add information in an empty cell in the column that is after the rest of the information that was entered by the form.

Example: Someone submits a form requesting technical help. Form contains 3 columns of information. Form should then mark the case as an opened case in a 4th column by entering "open case" in the cell.

Perhaps there is an onEdit() solution...

Any help writing this script would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `onFormSubmit` trigger. More information can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events). You will want to used the `e.range` parameter to figure out where to put the additional information.